# Multi-Screen adaptation android

Tags: android, image, multiscreen

I developed an android app that is designated to multi screens. 
I have my background images in all kind of sizes. divided into sub-folders for hdpi mhdpi xhdpi and xxhdpi.

On my Galaxy S4 the pictures look great, but when i installed the app on a tablet of 8 inch screen with low density the pictures looked really stretched.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

just pot diffrent images in XDPI MDPI AND LDPI with same name 
then Chek which one is getting detected in perticular device 
then you knw it.

Answer (score 0):

You are also creating a layout for each screen size? maybe the imageview is changing the size with each screen size.

Comment: no i don'n have different layouts, i read somewhere that all i need i different folders with all the images, apparently not working

Comment: Then you must to read this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) .